# Can't install Ruby 2.3.0 with rvm 1.26.11 (OSX Yosemite)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

Trying to figure out why I am unable to install `ruby 2.3.0`

## Steps Taken:

- made sure I had latest stable version of rvm by running `rvm get stable`
- made sure to update homebrew (suggested on a stackoverflow post) by running `brew update`
- made sure that xcode command lines tools are up to date for OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)
- run `rvm install 2.3.0` command while on global gemset

## Error Message:

rvm install 2.3.0

```
ruby  
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.3.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/uzzar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.3.0 - #downloading ruby-2.3.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.3.0 - #extracting ruby-2.3.0 to /Users/uzzar/.rvm/src/ruby-2.3.0....
Error running '__rvm_package_extract /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar. bz2 /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_75065',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/uzzar/.rvm/log/1452550299_ruby-2.3.0/extract.log
++ [[ -d /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.65tKWmz0 ]]
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ __rvm_tar xjf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 -C /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.65tKWmz0
++ tar xjf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 -C /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.65tKWmz0
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
++ return 1
++ return 1
++ __return=1
++ ((  __return == 0  ))
++ [[ -n /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.65tKWmz0 ]]
++ command rm -rf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.65tKWmz0
++ rm -rf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.65tKWmz0
++ return 1
There has been an error while trying to extract the source. Halting the installation.
There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

## Output of `/Users/uzzar/.rvm/log/1452549742_ruby-2.3.0/extract.log`:

```
ruby  
[2016-01-11 17:02:22] __rvm_package_extract__rvm_package_extract () 
{ 
    rvm_debug __rvm_package_extract:$#: "$@";
    \typeset __tempdir __path __file __return;
    __return=0;
    __tempdir="$( TMPDIR="${rvm_tmp_path}" mktemp -d -t rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX     )";
    __rvm_package_extract_run "$1" "$__tempdir" || __return=$?;
    if (( __return == 0 )); then
        for __path in "$__tempdir"/*;
        do
            __file="${__path##*/}";
            if [[ -n "${__file}" && -e "$2/${__file}" ]]; then
                \command \rm -rf "$2/${__file}" || __return=$?;
            fi;
            \command \mv -f "${__path}" "$2/" || __return=$?;
        done;
    fi;
    if [[ -n "$__tempdir" ]]; then
        \command \rm -rf "$__tempdir";
    fi;
    return $__return
}
current path: /Users/uzzar/.rvm/src
GEM_HOME=/Users/uzzar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/uzzar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/uzzar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/uzzar/.rvm/bin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:/Users/uzzar/.nvm/v0.10.36/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/uzzar/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/uzzar/.nvm/nvm.sh:/Users/uzzar/.node/bin:/usr/local/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/uzzar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
command(3): __rvm_package_extract /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_75065
++ rvm_debug __rvm_package_extract:2: /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_75065
++ ((  0  ))
++ return 0
++ typeset __tempdir __path __file __return
++ __return=0
+++ TMPDIR=/Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp
+++ mktemp -d -t rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX
++ __tempdir=/Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se
++ __rvm_package_extract_run /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se
++ [[    != *\ \-\-\n\o\-\s\a\m\e\-\o\w\n\e\r\ * ]]
++ __rvm_tar --help
++ __rvm_grep -- --no-same-owner
++ GREP_OPTIONS=
++ command grep -- --no-same-owner
++ grep -- --no-same-owner
++ return 1
++ [[ -d /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se ]]
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -n '' ]]
++ __rvm_tar xjf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 -C /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se
++ tar xjf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2 -C /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
++ return 1
++ return 1
++ __return=1
++ ((  __return == 0  ))
++ [[ -n /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se ]]
++ command rm -rf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se
++ rm -rf /Users/uzzar/.rvm/tmp/rvm-tmp.XXXXXXXXX.mARyv1Se
++ return 1
```

Looked in `/Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2` to see what I could find and I got this:

```
html    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>BPL Wireless Internet Access</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        html { font-size: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
        form { margin: 0; }
        label { cursor: pointer; }
        button, input { font-size: 100%; margin: 0; vertical-align: baseline; *vertical-    align: middle; line-height: normal; *overflow: visible; }
    button::-moz-focus-inner, input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; padding: 0; }

        a, a:visited, a:active {color: #1682b9; text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover {color: #444;}

        .hidden { display: none; }

        body {
          margin: 0;
          padding:0;
          background: #fff;
          color: #333;
          font-size: 14px;
          line-height: 1.4em;
          font-family: futura, arial, sans-serif;
        }

        h1 { font-family: helvetica, helvetica neue, futura, arial, sans-serif; }
        h1 {
          font-size: 24px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #676767;
          margin: 0;
        }
        h2 {
          font-size: 14px;
          font-weight: normal;
          margin-bottom:10px;
        }

        ul {margin:8px 8px 8px 24px; padding:0}
        li {padding-bottom:8px}


        #container {
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: auto;
          width: 100%
        }

        .header {
          background: #ececeb;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        }

        .header h1 { background: url(images/header2.png) no-repeat #ececeb; height:93px; text-indent:-9999px}


        #content {margin:0 0 0 15px; max-width:885px}

        #contentwrapper{
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        }

        #msg_col {
          margin-left:238px;
        }

        #msg_col p {margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:0; font-weight:bold}

        #button_col {
          float: left;
          width: 220px;
          margin-left: -100%
        }

        .color_button {
          font-size: 18px;
          padding: 8px 20px;
          -moz-border-radius: 3px;
          border: 1px solid #325098;
          border-radius: 3px;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 600;
          background: #4060ad;
          white-space: nowrap;
          display: inline-block;
          box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #ddd;
          }

        .color_button:hover, .color_button:focus {
          background: #345197;
        }

        .color_button a {
          padding: 12px 3px;
          display: block;
          border: none;
          background: none;
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
          color: #fff;
          margin: -3px auto;
          cursor: pointer;
        }


        #footer {
          clear: both;
          padding: 0;
          margin: 2em 15px 20px 15px;
          color: #444;
          max-width:870px
        }


        #footer-items {margin:0; padding:0;}
        #footer-items li.boxit {
            list-style:none;
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px 0 0 0;
            padding:0;
            width:33%
            }

      #footer-items li h2 {
          border-bottom:1px dotted #aaa;
          }


        #footer-items li div {
            font-size: 12px;
            padding:0 34px 0 0
            }

        #footer-items img {
            float:left; 
            padding:0 10px 4px 0
            }

        #connect {margin:0}
        #connect li {margin:0 14px 14px 0; display:inline; float:left; width:32px; text-indent:-9999px;}
        #connect li a {background: url(images/connect.png?x=5) no-repeat;  display: block; height:32px;}
        #connect li a.facebook {background-position:0 0}
        #connect li a.twitter {background-position:0px -32px}
        #connect li a.flickr {background-position:0px -64px}
        #connect li a.youtube {background-position:0px -96px}
        #connect li a.instagram {background-position:0px -128px}

        #credits {clear:both; overflow:auto; margin: 230px 15px 10px 15px;}
        #credits img {padding:0 10px 0 10px; vertical-align:top}

        /* styles for handheld devices */
        @media only screen
        and (max-width : 480px) {

        .header h1 { background: #ececeb url(images/logobpl_sm.png) no-repeat 5px     7px; height:44px; text-indent:0; padding:10px 5px 5px 140px; color:#333; font-    size: 18px; line-height:1.2}

        #contentwrapper{
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        }

        #msg_col {
          margin-left:0;
        }

        #button_col {
          float: none;
          width: 100%;
          margin-left: 0
        }

        .color_button {width:80%; text-align:center}

        #footer-items li.boxit {
            list-style:none;
            display:block;
            float:none;
            margin:10px 0 10px 0;
            padding:5px 0 0;
            width:100%;
            clear: both
            }

        #footer-items li div {
            padding:0 5px 0 0
            }


        #connect li {
            list-style:none;
            display:inline;
            width:32px;
            float:left;
            }

        }

        #mobileapp {background:#5e6b73 url(images/apple-phone2.png) no-repeat 15px bottom; height:110px; max-height:120px; padding:0px 10px 0 112px; margin-top:-1em; margin-bottom:1em; color:#fff;}
        #mobileapp h2 {font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; margin-bottom:5px; padding-top:10px; color:#fff}
        #mobileapp a {color:#fff; text-decoration:underline}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>


  <div id="container">

    <div class="header">
      <h1>Wireless Internet Access</span></h1>
    </div>

    <div id="mobileapp"><h2>Stay connected to BPL while on the go!</h2><a href="https://n28.network-auth.com/splash/grant?continue_url=http://www.bklynlibrary.org/my-bpl-mobile-apps">Download the My BPL mobile app</a> for iPhone&reg; and Android&#8482;.</div>

  <div id="content">


<div id="contentwrapper">
  <div id="msg_col">

    <p>Brooklyn Public Library is happy to provide you with free WiFi internet access</p>

    <ul>
      <li>Use of BPL's wireless networks to commit any crime -- including identity theft, the viewing and downloading of child pornography, and the illegal downloading of copyrighted materials is strictly prohibited. Violators may be prosecuted.</li>

      <li>The Library's wireless network is not secure. Information sent to and from your laptop can be captured by anyone else with a wireless device and the appropriate software.</li>

      <li>Library staff is not able to provide technical assistance for your device. BPL cannot guarantee a wireless connection.</li>

      <li>The Library assumes no responsibility for the safety of equipment or for laptop configurations, security, or data files resulting from connection to the Library's network.</li>

      <li>Laptops, cords and adapters must be properly connected to electrical outlets in a safe manner.</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="button_col">
    <div class="color_button wider">
        <a href="https://n28.network-auth.com/splash/grant?continue_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bklynlibrary.org%2F" title="Agree & Continue" id="continue_link">Agree &amp; Continue</a>
      </div>
  </div>



    </div>

  <div id="footer">

  <ul id="footer-items">

  <li class="boxit">
    <div>
    <h2>Get a Library Card</h2>

    <a href="https://n28.network-auth.com/splash/grant?continue_url=https://bpl.brooklynpubliclibrary.org/patron/registration.aspx" title="Sign up for a library card."><img src="images/newcard.png" alt="Library Card" width="112" height="75" border="0">Sign up now</a> for a BPL library card.

    </div>

  </li>
  <li class="boxit">
    <h2>Connect with BPL</h2>
    <div>

    <ul id="connect">
      <li><a href="https://n28.network-auth.com/splash/grant?continue_url=http://www.facebook.com/BrooklynPublicLibrary" class="facebook" title="facebook">facebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://n28.network-auth.com/splash/grant?continue_url=http://twitter.com/BKLYNlibrary" class="twitter">twitter</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://n28.network-auth.com/splash/grant?continue_url=http://instagram.com/BKLYNlibrary" class="instagram" title="instagram">instagram</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://n28.network-auth.com/splash/grant?continue_url=http:// www.youtube.com/user/BPLvideos" class="youtube">youtube</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>

  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="credits">
  Powered by: 
  <img src="images/twcable.png" alt="Time Warner Cable" width="100" height="40" border="0">
  <img src="images/powertolearn.png" alt="Power to Learn - a service of CABLEVISION" width="160" height="40" border="0">
  </div>

  </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

The contents of  `/Users/uzzar/.rvm/archives/ruby-2.3.0.tar.bz2` suggests that I might be having this problem due to access to internet? Not sure but would appreciate your help/explanation.

Thank you

Comment: Error message is _Unrecognized archive format_ and the file extension is `.bz2`. Do you have `bzip2` compression tool installed?

Comment: It seems your internet provider (in this case, your public library) somehow interferes with the download. Also, at least I needed the git master of RVM to install Ruby 2.3. Use `rvm get head` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to open up your web browser and accept their terms of service. There's a connect link in the file that got downloaded by rvm.

Once that is set up the requests should probably work and it will download the proper file instead of getting redirected to a wifi splash screen.

You might also try a different wireless hotspot.